# What is the geometric meaning of singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could anyone help explain what is the geometric meaning of singular matrix ? What's the difference between singular and non-singular matrix ? I know the definition, but couldn't understand it very well.

Thanks.

Comment: The singular matrix has no inverse matrix. This means that the operator described by the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Look at $\mathbb{R^3}$, for example. A singular $3\times 3$ real matrix maps $\mathbb{R^3}$ into a *proper* subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$ (a plane through the origin, a line through the origin, or, most degenerately, to just the origin). A non-singular matrix maps $\mathbb{R^3}$ *onto* itself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A matrix can be thought of as a linear function from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$. Typically, one is concerned with $n\times n$ real matrices, which are linear functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$. An $n\times n$ real matrix is *non-singular* if its image as a function is all of $\mathbb R^n$ and *singular* otherwise. More intuitively, it is singular if it misses some point in $n$-dimensional space and non-singular if it doesn't.

Comment: It's right of course, but "if it misses _some_ point" may give a bit of a bad picture: as soon as it misses any point at all, it necessarily has to miss _almost all_ of them. Which IMO gives a better impression of a singular linear mapping.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't get the *miss almost all* comment. For example if $Im(f)$ is $n/2\leq k<n$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ hits more than half of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in some sense, and not "misses almost all".

Comment: @rschwieb in _some_ sense it hits more than half of the points, but not in a canonical sense. Of course, these spaces have all uncountable-infinitely many points in them; "how many points" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ generally refers to the Lebesgue measure, which is zero for any proper subspace. _Almost all points lie outside of it_ may be a somewhat colloquial way of saying this, but it's widely accepted.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ok thanks for clarifying. Measure theory was very far from my mind in this algebraic problem.

Answer (score 28):

If you are in $\Bbb{R}^3$, say you have a matrix like

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{array}\right].$$

Now you can think of the columns of this matrix to be the "vectors" corresponding to the sides of a parallelepiped. If this matrix is singular i.e. has determinant zero, then this corresponds to the parallelepiped being completely squashed, a line or just a point.

Comment: It could also be an 1D object, or even a 0D object (zero matrix).

Comment: 11 upvotes for such an answer? I don't get Math.SE.....

Answer (score 21):

You can think of a $n \times n$ *normal* matrix as a linear transformation. It 'stretches' or 'scale' a vector in each of its eigenvector directions by factor of eigenvalues, which could be a complex number.

If there are $m$ zero eigenvalues and the $m$ independent corresponding eigenvectors, you can interpret it as the matrix wipes out $m$ dimensions in the $n$ dimensional vector space, or $m$ dimensions are  squashed or collapse, as described in BenjaLim's answer. The annihilated $m$ dimensions is called the null space or kernel of the matrix, and the remained $n-m$ dimensions is the co-image of the matrix, whose dimension ($n-m$ in this case) is the rank of the matrix.

If the matrix has null space (zero eigenvalues), you cannot invert it because information in the null space are lost, just as you cannot invert $0 \times a = b$ by $a = b/0$. The best you can do is to recover the information in the co-image space by pseudo-inverse.

Answer (score 2):

A nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix with real (or complex) entries corresponds to a linear transformation of ${\mathbb R}^n$ (or ${\mathbb C}^n$) to itself that is one-to-one and onto.  A singular matrix corresponds to a linear transformation that is neither one-to-one nor onto.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, zero determinant of a matrix with nonzero entries shows the balance like the resultant of two equal forces in opposite direction is zero or equilibrium state.