# Expanding on the intuitive meaning of singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, intuition

My question is based on ["What is the geometric meaning of singular matrix"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166021/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-singular-matrix) posted here some years ago.

To make this a bit more intuitive I would like to add an example.

A three-dimensional force vector $F$ applied at a point $P$ with coordinates $(x, y, z)$ creates a moment $M$ at, say, point $(0, 0, 0)$. This moment $M$ is again a vector with components $M_x$, $M_y$ and $M_z$ for which, the following hold:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & F_z & -F_y \\
    -F_z & 0 & F_x \\
    F_y & -F_x & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    M_x \\
    M_y \\
    M_z \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

As it can be seen, the above matrix is singular. Math tells me that as a result it cannot be inverted and consequently, given the forces and moments one cannot solve for the coordinates of $P$, aka 
**given the freedom to apply a given force wherever, not all moments vectors can be produced**.

Two questions come to mind here:

- How does one derive what (sub)part of $\mathbb R^3$ this given matrix embeds to? What points are reachable?
- How about the moments that can be produced? How would one solve for those?

---

One can easily construct a *solution-triplet* by setting $P$  to $(1, 1, 1)$ from which, $M=\begin{bmatrix}
    F_z - F_y \\
    F_x - F_z \\
    F_y - F_x \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

but assuming that instead of the $P$ we knew this $M$ how could $P$ be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment at $O = (0, 0, 0)$ is $\vec{M} = \vec{P} \times \vec{F}$. Geometrically, we can think of the moment as a vector that is perpendicular to both the force $\vec{F}$ and the vector $\vec{P}$ (right-hand rule), and length equal to the area of the parallelogram with sides $OF$ and $OP$. Thus, if the force is fixed, but you can vary $P$, you can achieve any point on the plane through 0, perpendicular to $\vec{F}$.

On the other hand, infinitely many points $P$ can give the same moment. We know $P$ must be on the plane through 0, perpendicular to $\vec{M}$. Further, we want the parallelogram with sides $OP$ and $OF$ to have area equal to $||\vec{M}||$. So $P$ must be on a line parallel to $\vec{F}$, at a distance $\frac{||\vec{M}||}{||\vec{F}||}$ from $O$. There are two of them (on the appropriate plane), and which one comes from the direction of the moment.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\vec{M} = \vec{P} \times \vec{F}$?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, indeed